# Problem with Asp.net core project publishing on localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, localhost, publish

I am trying to publish my asp.net core  3.1 project on IIS server.
I installed The .NET Core Hosting Bundle already.and publish my project on folder then I do settings for IIS pool and adding application and also  changing Identity field of my application pool to localsystem.All the things are OK and I run site and can see login page of my site but when i fill in the username and pass boxes I cant login!

This is My Connectionstring:

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source = DESKTOP-4QOAK53\SQLEXPRESS01 ; Initial Catalog = LeaveSheet;Connection Timeout=9000; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true ");
    }
```

*and in appsettings.json*

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
"MyConn": "Data Source=DESKTOP-4QOAK53\\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=LeaveSheet;Integrated security=true"},
```

and in sturtup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(p => p.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source = DESKTOP-4QOAK53\SQLEXPRESS01 ;Connection Timeout=3000 ; Initial Catalog = LeaveSheet; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true "));}
```

Comment: "i fill in the username and pass boxes I cant login". Since the login code is usually written by yourself, you are responsible to debug and learn what's wrong. If you want others to help, show the complete source code repo somewhere.

Comment: project works well with no error on visual studio running

Comment: There are far too many differences there when running in VS and on IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3, so no need for me to explain more.

Comment: I read your article all was about differences and .... but there isn't even one line about the solutions. beginners need to solution not to lecture. don't forget all programmers Including yourself have been beginners at first.

Comment: It seems that your application cannot connect to your database. If you use a database make sure your connection string is correct.

Comment: Yes but I don't know where is the problem I checked all the things is OK in VS (DatabaseContext , startup.cs, appsetings.development.json , appsetting.json );

Comment: What do you mean cannot login? Is there any error or exception show in page? Or it just didnot response and nothing changed?

Comment: Hi Bruce - Page do not respond and nothing changes. In login page if I input wrong password app should respond but nothing happens .

Comment: Is there any information in console? It seems that login request didnot send. Please use fiddler to check the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 days of reading and testing and experiencing all the things was OK and the problem was gone with just one check mark .
Finally I found under the Login section of SSMS on ***NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM*** should right click and select properties and then from Server Roles items ***sysadmin*** should also be check marked.
please don't forget to give me a PLUS if this answer was useful for you.