Error 500 or 404 when trying to connect localhost to the SQL Server DB by string in appsettings.json
I have SQL Server on the server. It has a username/password and a mixed auth. If I open port 1433 on the server and connect to the database via IP:Port, site works as it should.
A string in appsettings.json looks like this:
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=IP,Port; User ID='sa'; Password='password'; Database=DBName;"
}

But I want to turn off external database connection.
I need to write it in appsettings.json connectiong to the database as localhost.
Maybe I need some kind of permissions somewhere else?
How do I do this?
This line works on the home computer for the project in localhost.
But it does not work on the server.
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

I've tried different variants. Either it doesn't work or it works, but somehow partially with errors.
I see such error in log:

2024-07-28T09:24:50.2366385+03:00 INFO    [Project.Utility.NotFoundMiddleware]    [0] Handling 404 error for request /Home/Error

I see such errors in browser:
404 or 500

Error 500 just means "internal server error" and could mean anything; get the actual error from the logs, debugging, etc.

What confuses me is that you want to turn of remote connecties, but it looks like you're trying to connect from a remote.

LocalDB is minimum installation feature targeted for developers. You might have full SQL Server version installed at server and connection string would be different. Try generating connection string from Visual Studio and test it. If you can't connect remotely due to security configuration, you might need Remote Desktop.

I have a project on the server that I am publishing. I just wanted to connect it locally (localhost). There is the same database on the server, but locally the project cannot connect to it for some reason. It is connected only by IP,Port (from any location). And I need that, if it is on the server, it connects to the same database there via localhost. I didn't even think that there might be a problem, but there is.

In Win Event Viewer, I see (Source: MSSQLSERVER): Login failed for user 'cw0090005'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 45.135.232.28] if I try to connect locally to the database using the line specified above.

That error is telling you the problem; what about the error did you not understand?

It doesn't help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68567372/problem-with-asp-net-core-project-publishing-on-localhost

When a site tries to lift something from the database in localhost - in Win Event Viewer see: An account was logged off. Logon Type: 4. LogName: Security. Event Id: 4634. This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer. ____In SiteLog I see many: INFO [Project.Utility.NotFoundMiddleware] [0] Handling 404 error for request /Home/Error. In browser 404.

The problem was solved based on this post:
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'
Only I did it for the site.
IIS APPPOOL\site.com
IIS APPPOOL\www.site.com
And everything worked. :)
The string should look like this:
"DefaultConnection": "Server=[SERVER_NAME];Database=[DB_Name];Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
...And you can safely close port 1433.
Good luck!
